# What is wrong in this block of JQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I have the below code:

```
 var isError = false;

    $('input, textarea').each(function(index) {
     if ($(this).val() === "") {
            isError = true;
            break;//basically want to break if any one of them is empty and gonna //use this isError value outside
     }
    });
```

But I am getting "can't have break outside of loop" error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you don't understand. You don't have a loop, so there's nothing to `break` from.

Comment: try if (($(this).val()) === "") {

Comment: use return instead of the break

Comment: @Hushme no, triple `===` is better than `==`

Comment: Sorry for asking duplicate question, my bad!